# Irreducible representation and base change of fields

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $k$ an algebraically closed field, and $V$ be a finite dimensional irreducible $k$-representation of $G$. Consider a field extension $L/k$, must $V_L=V \otimes_k L$ still be irreducible?

Motivation: this is a continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737361/trivial-subrepresentation-and-base-change-of-fields), from which we know $\operatorname{Hom}_G(V,V) \otimes_k L= \operatorname{Hom}_G(V_L,V_L)$ i.e $End_G(V_L)=L$ hence $V_L$ is indecomposible. If $V$ is semisimple (for example when $k=\Bbb C$ and $G$ is finite) then we know $V$ is irreducible. I am interested in the general case, and without loss of generality we can assume $G$ is closed subgroup of $GL(V)$ over $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  The idea is that an invariant subspace of $V_L$ can be described using only finitely many elements of $L$.  By the Nullstellensatz, there is a homomorphism from the $k$-subalgebra generated by these elements to $k$, which then gives an invariant subspace of $V$.

Suppose we have an invariant subspace $U\subseteq V_L$ of dimension $m$.  Let $i:U\to V_L$ be the inclusion map and let $p:V_L\to U$ be a linear projection.  Choose a basis of $U$ and a basis of $V$ (and thus also a basis of $V_L$) and represent $p$ and $i$ as matrices.  Let $A\subseteq L$ be the $k$-subalgebra generated by all the entries in these two matrices.  Note that for any $g\in G$, we can recover the action of $g$ on $U$ as the composition $p\circ g\circ i$.  Since the action of $g$ on $V_L$ is represented by a matrix with entries in $k$, this means the action of $g$ on $U$ is represented by a matrix with entries in $A$.  So, using these matrices, we can construct everything over the ring $A$ instead of over $L$: we can equip the free $A$-module $U_A=A^m$ with an action of $G$ and homomorphisms $i_A:U_A\to V_A$ and $p_A:V_A\to U_A$ such that $U\cong U_A\otimes_A L$ (as a representation of $G$) and $i$ and $p$ are similarly obtained by tensoring $i_A$ and $p_A$ up to $L$.  Moreover, $i_A$ is $G$-equivariant, and $p_Ai_A=1_{U_A}$.

Now $A$ is a nonzero reduced finitely generated $k$-algebra.  By the Nullstellensatz, there exists a $k$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi:A\to k$.  Consider the tensor product $U_k=U_A\otimes_A k$, where we consider $k$ as an $A$-algebra via $\varphi$.  We then have homomorphisms $i_k:U_k\to V_A\otimes_A k=V$ and $p_k:V\to U_k$, where $i_k$ is $G$-equivariant and $p_ki_k=1_{U_k}$.  This means that the image of $i_k$ is an invariant subspace of $V$, of dimension $m$ (since $i_k$ has a left inverse and so is injective).  By irreducibility of $V$, we must have either $m=0$ or $m=\dim V$.  Thus either $U=0$ or $U=V_L$, as desired.

(If you find these tensor products confusing, in concrete terms all we're doing is applying the homomorphism $\varphi$ to the entries of the matrices representing $p$ and $i$ and the action of $G$ on $U$, and after doing this the image of $i$ will be an invariant subspace of $V$.)